# How to test one function of a class and how to avoid some code when test a function?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

Sample code:

```
function TestClass() {
  var this.name = 'test';
  var this.host = '...';
  var this.port = '...';
  //...
  this.connection = this.createConnection(....);
}

TestClass.prototype.testFunc = function(data) {
  if(data == this.name) {
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}

Testclass.prototype.createConnection = function (...) {
   //some code
  //a real HTTP connection will be created
  //some code
}
```

Now I want to test testFunc, it has a class variable `this.name`, so I have to create a TestClass instance. But if I create TestClass instance, a real HTTP connection will be created. How can I avoid this real HTTP connection when testing?

In situation like this, how can I write the test code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to simply re-define `createConnection` in your test, before you instantiate `TestClass`.

```
TestClass.prototype.createConnection = function() {
    console.log("Called redefined createConnection");
}
```

Comment: Does rewriting the code is the only way? What if just a tester, does not have the permission and responsible to modify the code.

Comment: If you have access to the class in a test, then you have access to modify it. JavaScript is very dynamic... But of course, depending on what your `createConnection` method actually do, you  might be able to apply mocking at some other level. You can also probably achieve the same with [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) and `sinon.stub()` (although I'm not quite sure, since it calls it from the "constructor").

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the dependency that make the request not your class you wanna test. Take a look at this [nock](https://github.com/flatiron/nock), a HTTP mocking and expectations library